# 500 Internal Server Error", error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined

Tags: node.js, angular, http-post, internal-server-error

I need your help. I am new here and also as a developer.

I am currently developing my first Angular App with a backend REST server in Node.js. Everything works fine in localhost, but when it is deployed it in Heroku I get a backend error when trying to make a POST request. GET requests work fine.

**This is the error message I get from the browser console:**

> "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for
> https://my-json-rest-server.herokuapp.com/cars: 500 Internal Server
> Error", error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined\n
> at Function.createId

**This is the error from the Heroku backend server log:**

> 2020-10-22T17:13:14.526984+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
> path="/cars" host=my-json-rest-server.herokuapp.com
> request_id=0892bf3c-3982-4ba1-bccb-4cd7e61a8a76 fwd="xx.xx.209.133"
> dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=6ms status=500 bytes=1198
> protocol=https

**I am using the "json-server" Node.js module as backend.**

**This is the code I use in Angular:**

```
 public sendPostRequest() {
    console.log('POST');
       
     this.httpClient.post(this.REST_API_SERVER,
        {
    Name: "Porche 911 GT3",
    Miles_per_Gallon: 10,
    Cylinders2: 6,
    Displacement: 5,
    Horsepower: 580,
    Weight_in_lbs: 3500,
    Acceleration: 3.5,
    Year: "2005",
    Origin: "Europe"
        })
        
          .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.ngUnsubscribe)
            )
        
        .subscribe(
        data  => {
        console.log("POST Request is successful ", data);
        
        }
                 );
```

I hope this info helps.

Thanks for your help :)!!

Comment: Maybe better to show your backend code?

Comment: a error 500 is about an error in your server. You has a function in your server `createId` that need a variable `id` and this variable is null or undefined. You need control this case using a "if"

Comment: Thanks for your replies!. I think I already fixed it up. The problem is that I didn include an "id" field when making the request to the server.